# What method should I use in Yii 1.1 to sum in MySQL?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

What method mysql use in Yii 1.1 when adding?
Here is the code I use but the sum method does not work:

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->from('users_payouts');
sum = $query->sum('sum');
```

In the browser, it gives an error:

> In the CDbCommand class and its behaviors, no method or closure named "sum" was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shortcut for sum, you should define correct `select`:

```
$sum = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('SUM(some_column)')
    ->from('users_payouts')
    ->queryScalar();
```